# How to bridge eth from Arbitrum Rinkeby Layer2 to Ethereum Mainnet?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, arbitrum

Does anyone know how to move eth from an Arbitrum Rinkeby Layer2 Network back to Ethereum Mainnet?
I looked into [Arbitrum Bridge](https://bridge.arbitrum.io/) but it doesn't support Arbitrum Rinkeby Network.
Anyone know how I can get around this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Rinkeby is a testnet and its ether has no value therefore u can’t move it to mainnet !!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Use goerli or sepolia faucet.
https://goerli-faucet.pk910.de/ or https://sepolia-faucet.pk910.de/ or alchemy faucet(https://goerlifaucet.com/)

Good luck:)

Comment: P.S. Rinkeby is testnet, it's not same mainnet

Comment: your comment is better than your current answer, the point should be you cannot move testnet ETH to mainnet